# Analyzing rhetorical strategies used

Tags: homework

This [essay question](http://matermiddlehigh.org/ourpages/auto/2010/1/25/34429805/2001%20AP%20English%20Language%20and%20Composition%20Free%20Response%20Questions.pdf) [PDF] prompts:

> Read the letter carefully. Then write an essay in which you analyze the rhetorical strategies Lewes uses to establish her position about the development of a writer. (Question 1)

I am unsure what is meant by "development of a writer", much less what strategies are used to "establish her position".

Any advice on where to begin would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression "*development of a writer*" should be interpreted as "*how one becomes a writer*", while the expression "*establish her position*" simply means "*establish her point of view*". [Rhetorical strategies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_strategies) can be thought of as the efforts made by the author to persuade or inform the readers. So basically you are asked to write an essay in which you analyze the efforts made by Marian Evans Lewes to establish her point of view about how one becomes a writer.

[Here](http://www.writework.com/essay/ap-prompt-essay-discussing-writers-must-prepare-unsatisfie) is a sample of the essay. [Here](http://authspot.com/thoughts/george-eliot-excerpt/) is another one.